# shift from localhost to 127 server in laravel

Tags: laravel, localhost, artisan-serve

I design my page in localhost which works fine and I include all my paths like that

```
<link href="{{ asset('public/'.Config::get('config.template_assets').'assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

but when I run my php artisan serve bootstrap is not including with 404 error ,which mean my server can't found the location of bootstrap, so how should I change my path so that it should be compatible for both localhost and 127 server. And if I remove public from path it works fine

Comment: Bootstrap should be included in `app.css` when you compiled your assets (`npm run dev`). Have you made sure that the file exists at that location? `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` should work the same.

Comment: issue is not only for bootstrap .issue is for all css , script and images so I have to make one path for all which can be accessed by both localhost and 127.0.0.1

Comment: So have you made sure that the files exist? `public/`  should not appear in any url, it's the "DocumentRoot" for your server. `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">` or a simple `<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">` should load `app.css` from `public/css/app.css` - adapt accordingly

Comment: in localhost it don't load from public folder it load from root folder

Comment: What? Are you running two servers? localhost and 127.0.0.1 are basically the same. If "on localhost" it is loading from the root folder your server has a wrong setup! As I said "_`public/` should not appear in any url, it's the "DocumentRoot" for your server._"